# make an alias that runs scripts

Tags: linux, alias

i would like an alias that when i type

```
[Floodgate]~$: bash (pluginname)
```

in terminal it runs

```
[Floodgate]~$: . ~/bash\ plugins/(pluginname)
```

so far every alias i have tried has run

```
[Floodgate]~$: . ~/bash\ plugins/ (pluginname)
```

where the space between the slash and the (pluginname) is causing issues.
it would be really nice to not have to make a new alias for every plugin but have one universal. so far the only thing that works is

```
alias bash='cd ~/bash\ plugins; .'
```

but that leaves me in

```
[Floodgate]~/bash plugins/$:
```

==================================================================================

thank you for all of your help! it was  much appreciated

==================================================================================

Comment: Simply add the directory containing your scripts (e.g. `$HOME/scripts/`) to your `$PATH` (do that in `~/.bashrc`). I advise against spaces in file or directory names.

Comment: Naming an alias `bash` seems like a wee bit of a bad idea... Perhaps a function would be a better plan - something like `plug() { . ~/bash\ plugins/${1} }` but with a bit more error checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Basile Starynkevitch above, the easiest way to accomplish this is to: (1) make sure the files in your ~/bash\ plugins directory are executable by you (and they contain valid shell commands). e.g.

```
chmod 0755 ~/bash\ plugins/*
```

Then include ~/bash\ plugins in your path. In your ~/.bashrc include:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bash\ plugins
```

Now to run your bash plugins, you can simply call them by name at the command prompt:

```
$ pluginname
```

There are many ways to do this. You can even create a function withing your .bashrc that takes the plugin names as an input and then executes the plugin, E.g. inside .bashrc:

```
function exeplugins {
   [[ -n $1 ]] || { echo "error: this command requires pluginname as input"; return 1; }
   bash "~/bash plugin/${1}"
}

alias bplugin='exeplugins'  # or any alias name you want 'bplugin' to be...
```

Now from the comman line you could simply do:

```
$ bplugin pluginname
```

Hope this helps. (+1 don't make an alias named 'bash' - bad juju follows)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not to name the alias "bash" since this is the command for opening a new bash and it can cause you problems with other applications or scripts. Otherwise this should work:

```
  alias openplugin="cd ~/bash\ plugins && cd"
```